# C++ return reference push instruction not showing up in assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, att, calling-convention

I'm trying to learn more about how return references are compiled, and I'm currently stuck on how they show up in assembly. The code I'm running is this:

```
struct Obj {
    char buf[100];
    int i;
    long b;
} B, B2;

Obj foo(Obj b) {
  b.i = 100; // Do something to the argument
  return b;
}

int main() {

  B2 = foo(B);
}
```

and the assembly code looks like this:

```
    .file   "return_function_assembly.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  B
    .bss
    .align 32
    .type   B, @object
    .size   B, 112
B:
    .zero   112
    .globl  B2
    .align 32
    .type   B2, @object
    .size   B2, 112
B2:
    .zero   112
    .text
    .globl  _Z3foo3Obj
    .type   _Z3foo3Obj, @function
_Z3foo3Obj:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $100, 116(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    16(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    24(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rdx, (%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 8(%rax)
    movq    32(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    40(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rdx, 16(%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 24(%rax)
    movq    48(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    56(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rdx, 32(%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 40(%rax)
    movq    64(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    72(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rdx, 48(%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 56(%rax)
    movq    80(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    88(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rdx, 64(%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 72(%rax)
    movq    96(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    104(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rdx, 80(%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 88(%rax)
    movq    112(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    120(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rdx, 96(%rax)
    movq    %rcx, 104(%rax)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _Z3foo3Obj, .-_Z3foo3Obj
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    addq    $-128, %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leaq    -128(%rbp), %rax
    pushq   104+B(%rip)
    pushq   96+B(%rip)
    pushq   88+B(%rip)
    pushq   80+B(%rip)
    pushq   72+B(%rip)
    pushq   64+B(%rip)
    pushq   56+B(%rip)
    pushq   48+B(%rip)
    pushq   40+B(%rip)
    pushq   32+B(%rip)
    pushq   24+B(%rip)
    pushq   16+B(%rip)
    pushq   8+B(%rip)
    pushq   B(%rip)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _Z3foo3Obj
    addq    $112, %rsp
    movq    -128(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -120(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, B2(%rip)
    movq    %rdx, 8+B2(%rip)
    movq    -112(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -104(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, 16+B2(%rip)
    movq    %rdx, 24+B2(%rip)
    movq    -96(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -88(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, 32+B2(%rip)
    movq    %rdx, 40+B2(%rip)
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, 48+B2(%rip)
    movq    %rdx, 56+B2(%rip)
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -56(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, 64+B2(%rip)
    movq    %rdx, 72+B2(%rip)
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, 80+B2(%rip)
    movq    %rdx, 88+B2(%rip)
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, 96+B2(%rip)
    movq    %rdx, 104+B2(%rip)
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
    je  .L5
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L5:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

System is Linux, compiled with g++, and from my understanding of function frames, I should be seeing an additional "push" instruction that pushes the address of B2 onto the stack prior the call instruction in the function frame.

However, none of these push instructions seem to correspond to what I'm looking for. I see a leaq instruction, and a pushq (%rbp) at the beginning of main, but nothing that seems to be what I'm supposed to be seeing. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: `foo` does not return by reference but by value. Hence, foo is first writing to stack which is then copied by main into B2. `leaq -128(%rbp), %rax` allocates the memory required for this return value.

Comment: Compiling with optimization enabled yields much more readable assembly code with less clutter.

Comment: Small arguments are passed in registers, so even if a reference to B2 were being passed, it wouldn’t be a push, but rather a load into a register. The argument B is passed on the stack because it is large.

Comment: @Trick or Treat: okay, I see. I was definitely confused because 2 different sources cited (one is "Thinking in C++ Vol. 1" , the other is a different source I can't recall right now) that memory for the return address was usually allocated on the stack.

From the purposes of documentation, page 22 of [Calling conventions for different compilers](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) contains the information that I am looking for, which you have also confirmed (structs greater than 128-bits are returned as pointers in AX, EAX, and RAX).

Comment: For a return value that is a struct larger than 128 bits, memory for the return value (*not* “return address”) *is* allocated on the stack before the call. A pointer to this space is passed to the function as a parameter (in RDI). (The pointer is also returned in RAX, but that is pretty useless, because the caller already knows the address, since it allocated the space.)